# Unity & Rider - References go AWOL after Git Commit

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, rider

I'm setting up a Unity project, create source files, open them in Rider: All looks good!

I commit it all to Git, come back into Rider and all references (`System`, `System.Core`, `UnityEditor`, `UnityEngine`, etc.) go missing. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

I remember back in the old days in VS we added references from the Unity DLLs manually. Does this still need to be done? I'm asking because I think this should not happen anymore.

EDIT: Deleting the broken references and re-adding them from the DLL files doesn't help. They still show the warning icon on them afterwards. Any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the Unity - Preferences - Rider - TargetFrameworkVersion checkbox.
Same issue https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/164

Comment: TargetFrameworkVersion was already checked but thanks for the link! Switching to MSBuild 4.0 in Rider fixed this (even though Rider now tells me .NET Framework 4.5 not installed. Even though I have VS 2017 installed which includes .NET 4.5).